# I can't boot installation live cd in uefi mode but i need to install uefi version of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

I can't boot installation live cd in uefi mode but i need to install uefi version of Ubuntu.

I have Toshiba Satellite L50-A-19N with Win10.
I realy hate windows but i need it because of school and i want to use me external usb3 hdd for ubuntu.

I've setted boot order and turned off all options in uefi/bios setup like SecureBoot, QuickBoot, etc...
But the LiveCD installation disc is still booting only in bios mode and install bios version on hdd. But for easy booting i need uefi version of Ubuntu on HDD.

So, can you please tell me how to boot liveCD only via UEFI or how to convert bios Ubuntu into UEFI Ubuntu?

I want to install newest Ubuntu 14, thank you for answers.
(Sorry for bad english)

Comment: You can manually partition external drive using gpt, make sure first partition is the ESP - efi system partition, include a bios_grub partition for BIOS boot, and install. Then use Boot-Repair to convert BIOS to UEFI version of grub. You then have to copy /EFI/ubuntu to external drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ***disable your Compatibility Support Module (CSM)***, aka "legacy mode support." Having it enabled complicates the boot path and sometimes directs the boot mode down that road even when you don't want it to do that. While you're in the firmware setup utility, you may want to re-enable Secure Boot. Although it does sometimes cause problems, it usually doesn't. (Many reports of Secure Boot problems actually have other causes.) You can always re-disable Secure Boot if you run out of other options. Secure Boot, as the name implies, is a security feature, so you probably shouldn't be disabling it unless you're certain you need to do so.

If that's not sufficient, use your firmware's boot manager. This tool is usually accessed by hitting Esc, Enter, or a function key (usually F8 or above). Most modern EFIs show two options for booting external boot media, one of which includes the string "UEFI" and the other of which doesn't. Pick the option that includes the string "UEFI" to boot in that mode.

If that doesn't work, then chances are your boot medium was prepared incorrectly. You didn't say what tool you used to create your USB drive, but quite a few are available. [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) seems to have the best reputation among Windows programs and [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) usually works and is cross-platform. Neither is guaranteed to work, though. Note that Rufus has at least three options for different partition table and boot loader combinations, so be sure to use an option for creating an EFI-compatible medium.

Comment: It was because of FastStartup in Windows, so now i installed (hopefully) UEFI ver of Ubuntu on my HDD, but now the HDD don't want to boot. In installation i followed this: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343352#343352) I even tried installing it twice with making ext4. / partition primary. Can it be caused by making swap on the begining of HDD? I think, UEFI don't see my HDD as bootable but i don't know why. (sorry for bad english)

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) and post the `RESULTS.txt` file that it produces to [a pastebin site.](http://paste.ubuntu.com) Post the URL to your document here. At this point, we need the detailed information that Boot Info Script provides to give you more than random guesses about what might be wrong.

Comment: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15197875/)
-
sda is windows internal HDD, 
scd is ubuntu external HDD

Comment: It looks like your Boot Info Script output was produced from a BIOS-mode boot, so it's lacking the critical `efibootmgr` output, which shows the EFI boot variables. It could be a simple boot-order repair will fix the problem; or you might need to do something more drastic, like rename GRUB (or install a boot manager as) `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`.

Comment: In legacy mode it shows error, so i think it tried to boot, and in uefi mode it doesn't boot even after chosing boot media from boot menu (sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0):

Good Day.. Actually you want to use both-of them why can't try **Virtual Box, or vm players ?** because it will-be useful for you.. you will choose Linux primary and boot window foe virtual . that is your option.

Comment: I taught about this too, but i have oem version of windows installed and i have to use cracked versions on VMs